# interesting news article/blog post scraping problem

Tags: c#, asp.net

i need to scrape the text of blog posts to build a summary description of the blog posts similar to what techmeme.com does. not a problem when it's one or a handful of blog posts. however, the possible blogs from which to scrape the text is variable and unlimited. how would you go about doing this?

i've used the html agility pack and yql in the past, but there's nothing built-in either of those solutions to handle this requirement.

one thought i had was to search for div ids and div attributes named things like content, post, article etc and see how that worked - not really leaning this direction. the other idea was to search for the biggest text node in the html document and assume that's the node i want - could lead to some false positives. the final idea was to endeavor to create a crowdsourced data repository on google apps that would allow for the community to manage (read: create, update, delete) the xpath mappings for most of the popular news/blog platforms then you could query this list by domain or blog platform type and get the requisite xpath - but this seems like a hella undertaking.

of course, i know some of you have ideas that will work better than any of my hare-brained ideas.

what are your thoughts?

Comment: My thoughts are that I absolutely despise sites that republish content from original authors like that. You're not only attempting to make money off of someone else's work, but you're polluting the search space. STOP IT.

Comment: Chris, you're assuming that you know what we're trying to do. STOP IT. We're only looking to get a summary akin to the website I mentioned above. Reading might help you in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The only sure-fire way of doing this is to have a class for each blog. That way you can do what you need in the implementation of each specific class for each specific blog.

So you'll have an abstract base class that processes a blog and returns the data/info you need from a blog.

for example

```
public abstract class BlogProcessor
{
  public abstract BlogResult ProcessBlog(string url);
}
```

Where BlogResult is a type you define that has all the information you'll need from a blog such as title, date, tags, post etc.

Each descendant knows how to extract this information for the blog is is specialized for.

If you call code you'll treat these descendant classes pollymorphic-ally like so:

```
foreach(var url in BlogsToParse)
{
  var blogProcessor = BlogProcessorFactory.CreateInstance(url);
  var blogResult = blogProcessor.ProcessBlog(url);
  /* Do Something with blogResult */
}
```

Does that make sense?

In the implementation of each "ProcessBlog" method you could use HtmlAgilityPack to do the specific parsing.

Comment: this can't work. we have no idea what the blogs are ahead of time. as i mentioned, "the possible blogs from which to scrape the text is variable and unlimited".

Comment: variable and unlimited does *not* imply unknown. Maybe you should be clearer and read you question before posting? :)

Comment: shiv, we can't have a class for each blog. that's not plausible. there are million of blogs on the internet. so, in that case, variable and unlimited surely implies unknown. unless we're speaking a different language here.